# Getting various slices from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to get various slices with determined length from a string.

On code below I don't know why the return from substring function doesn't match setted length.

I see matched value only on the first return, but then all results after are invalid.

```
class Counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String listBits = "5,1,1,5,0,5,3,3,2,0,2,3,1,1,0,";
        int width = 6;

        String stringSlice = "";
        int maxBeginSlice = listBits.length() - (width * 2) + 1;

        System.out.println(listBits);

        for (int x = 1; x <= maxBeginSlice; x = x + 2) {

            System.out.print((x - 1) + "->");

            stringSlice = listBits.substring(x - 1, width * 2);

            System.out.println(stringSlice);

        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
5,1,1,5,0,5,3,3,2,0,2,3,1,1,0,
0->5,1,1,5,0,5,
2->1,1,5,0,5,
4->1,5,0,5,
6->5,0,5,
8->0,5,
10->5,
12->
14->
```

With Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: -2
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
at Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Comment: Can you post the output you get and the output you want to get?

Comment: You are aware that it's not just the numbers that makes up the strings but also the comma, ',', characters between them?

Comment: All that I want is a slice of the same length from string in various position.

Comment: @GilbertoRodrigues, read the documentation on substring again. Second parameter is end index, not length.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson. Solved!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a fixed length slice then you need to change the end index, the second parameter to substring, according to the start position.

```
int endIndex = x - 1 + width * 2;
stringSlice = listBits.substring(x - 1, endIndex);
```

Of course you need to check endIndex against the string length as well

Answer (score 0):

```
String substring(int startIndex, int endIndex):
```

You need to fix your code and edit the `width` parameter.

```
listBits.substring(x - 1, width * 2); //edit width to your needs.
```

Comment: Dennis, width is a constant. As you see on the OUTPUT, the result of substring IS VARIANT ... This is my question. It must be constant and it isn't.

Comment: Daniel’s answer is exactly what I meant 

Comment: Now I understand, but the way you wrote I thought you didn't undestood about "width" variable. But now I see that you were talking about "endIndex" parameter. Thanks for your help too, @Denis Vash